# How to force p2 to set singleton=false in bundle iu definition

Tags: eclipse, p2

I'd like to force p2 so set **singleton='false'** to some of my bundle that are defined as singleton in their manifest.

I know that multiple singleton plugins cannot be activated at the same time in an Eclipse runtime, but I would like them to be installed (no in the OSGI sense), meaning present on the disc. I have implemented my own configurator to activate the required bundle according to some license file.

I have tried to modify the content.xml manually to add the **singleton='false'** attribute to all my bundle IUs and it works fine. But I'd like to know if there is a way using a p2.inf file ?

Thanks for any lead.

Answer (score 0):

The standard publishers that come with p2 cater for the standard Eclipse installation use case. The aim is to create an installation that will run, and fail the installation if it would fail at runtime. Therefore, I'd be surprised to see support for your use case in the standard p2 publishers.

Note however that you are free to write your own publishers. p2 (i.e. the entire project, not just the p2 publishers) aims to support all kinds of different installation scenarios and not only OSGi/Eclipse installations.